# Cytoscape.js - Get ".on(tap)" event position

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, mouse, cytoscape.js

How to get the `tap` event position?

Here, I'm trying to add a node on `tap`... but I couldn't figure out how to get the specific coordinates to pass to the `rendererPosition` property of the new node.

```
cy.on('tap', function (e) {
    if (e.cyTarget === cy) {                    
        //var pos = $(this).position().left,  //tried this, as jquery
        //posY = $(this).position().top;   //positioning without success        
        var idNum = cy.nodes().size();
        var setID = idNum.toString();
        cy.add([{
            group: "nodes",
            data: {
                id: "n" + setID
            },
            renderedPosition: {
                x: e.pageX, //- posX,
                y: e.pageY //- posY
            },
        }]);                        
    }    
});
```

Using the same code but binding with the `$('#cy').click` function, it works... but with `cy.on('tap')` way, the event **`e`** doesn't have the `pageX` and `pageY` properties, neither can I get the element position using the `$(this).position()` function.

I really prefer using `tap`, as I'm trying to develop my application also for mobile interfaces.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Using @darshanags observation and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780837/is-there-an-equivalent-to-e-pagex-position-for-touchstart-event-as-there-is-fo?rq=1), I solved this way:

```
var idNum = cy.nodes().size(),
    setID = idNum.toString(),
    offset = $("cy").offset(),
    position = {
        x: e.originalEvent.x - offset.left,
        y: e.originalEvent.y - offset.top
    };
cy.add([{
    group: "nodes",
    data: { id: "n" + setID },
    renderedPosition: {
        x: position.x,
        y: position.y
    },
    ...
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of is incorrect, Cytoscape's `.position()` works a bit differently to jQuery's `position()`:

Get the position and use it:

```
var idNum = cy.nodes().size(),
    setID = idNum.toString(),
    position = {
        x: e.cyTarget.position("x"),
        y: e.cyTarget.position("y")
    };

cy.add([{
    group : "nodes",
    data : {
        id : "n" + setID
    },
    renderedPosition : {
        x : position.x,
        y : position.y
    }
}]);
```

Docs: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#collection/position--dimensions/node.position

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help, but unfortunatelly it didn't work: `e.cyTarget.position` is `undefined`. Should it really exist? If so, I don't really know where else I'm wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I solved it with your observation. See edit. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: In 2.1 you will be able to use `e.cyPosition` and `e.cyRenderedPosition`

Answer (score 1):

I answered this [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115940/adding-cytoscape-node-at-the-location-of-mouse-cursor/53329006#53329006), but had come across both these questions while trying to make this work, so I'll post it here, too.

In cytoscape.js 3.2, there are convenience functions for this:

```
cy.on("tap", function(e) {
    cy.add([{
        group: "nodes",
        id: "testid",
        renderedPosition: {
            x: e.renderedPosition.x,
            y: e.renderedPosition.y,
        },
    });
});
```

This ends up being equivalent to (assuming you've set `container: $("#cy-container")`):

```
cy.on("tap", function(e) {
    let canvas = $("#cy-container").find("canvas").get(0);
    cy.add([{
        group: "nodes",
        id: "testid",
        renderedPosition: {
            x: e.originalEvent.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left,
            y: e.originalEvent.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top,
        },
    });
});
```